# What is the design principle to only assign a single meaning to a boolean variable?

Tags: design-patterns, boolean, boolean-logic

I'm pretty sure I was taught a long time ago that it's bad practice to use a boolean variable to hold information about more than one property. I've not been able to find the name of a design principle that covers this.

As an example, say we wanted to record whether a customer wanted milk and sugar in their drink. We'd have one variable for milk and one for sugar.

We wouldn't conflate these into variables milk&Sugar and milk&NoSugar because the choice of Sugar is in both variables, so what would it mean if both boolean variables were true? Does the customer want sugar or not?

But is there a name for this design principle?

(A colleague has tried to justify the latter, noting that this works if one boolean takes precedence over the other. Seniority rather than sense has prevailed!)

Comment: I think the Single Responsibility Principle could be applied here, but if there's a formal principle that is specific to boolean values, I'm unaware of it. Worth noting that, depending on the language you're using, you could achieve your goals here by using bitwise flags via enums.

Comment: You're looking for the wrong thing. You don't need a *name* for it. You need the rationale. Conflating two things in one value (boolean or not) makes the information *ambiguous*. And not very useful if you need the discrete parts of it. Let's say you have something called "nameAndAge" and you put both the name and the age of a person there. It becomes hard to sort the people by age. Or distinguish them by name. Values should be unambiguous in what they do. Overloading them with information is not useful.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ I was hoping to point my team lead to an authoritative source on this simple principle with perhaps a name of the principle. Totally agreed "conflating two things in one value (boolean or not) makes the information ambiguous". But hey that's what we're doing in a very successful company and "the power that be" are justifying it  with their authority rather than reason. It makes things super complicated very quickly and a simple task that should have taken no time at all ended up taking me a day to get round the ambiguity.

Comment: If nobody has put a name to this rationale, can I claim it? The Cooper principle - "don't conflate multiple properties into a single variable".

Comment: Then perhaps the approach you seek is wrong. I mean, yes, you're looking for a good authoritative explanation to back you up but what guarantee do you have that such a thing would be respected? There are numerous best practices but to be completely honest with you - they *aren't important*. What is important is the team to be open to improvements. You shouldn't have to dig out "ammo" to lend credence. Usually, raising an objection like "I don't think we should do X because of A and B" should be respected. Changing that to "because <this> says so" rarely makes for a stronger argument.

Comment: Whereas I agree that there is no one way to design complex systems and we should always evaluate competing "best practices" and not refer to a single authority, I was under the impression there would be no debate about the simple principle that I thought I'd learned decades ago regarding variable use, specifically booleans. Maybe it's covered in many courses, but just hasn't been named?

Comment: You want to store two bits of data. Using one `boolean` violates the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: Close @ElliottFrisch, but not specifically about computer programming. With my team lead asserting that it's OK to have 2 booleans one for "Property A AND Property B"  and the other for "Property A AND NOT Property B", where do I stand on arguing the case that the variables we need are simply "Property A" and "Property B". Furthermore, in our code base both the booleans can be true simultaneously because one takes priority over the other. Seriously?

Comment: @AlexCooper *If you don't eat your meat, you can't have any pudding!* -- Pink Floyd, The Wall